# How do I git stash my work, pull from github, and put my work back into project?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I am using source tree and was working on a project. I am making changes to my local repository. Someone else who is working on the project has made some change. What I want to do is stash everything that I have, pull what he pushed into my local, then bring everything that I stashed back into the project. How do I do this?

Comment: By stashing your work, pulling from github, and then applying the stask.

Answer (score 3):

You can add script as Custom Action to do the same in sourcetree
Script can contain

git stash && git pull --rebase && git stash pop

Comment: Note that for sourcetree, you need to make a file such as `myscript.sh`, and make it executable, such as `chmod u+x myscript.sh` and populate that file with the text mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

To stash your work:

```
git stash
```

Then make your pull and get your work back with:

```
git stash apply
```

At this point, you may have merging conflicts to fix. Once you're done with that, you can delete the stash entry:

```
git stash drop
```

[more on stashing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning)

Comment: Should include the option of using `git stash apply` in case he wants to keep the stashed changes!

Comment: This is the error I got. 
`error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
 Final-Questor-App.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/adrianhumphrey.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
 Final-Questor-App/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
` . Just lost all my work.

Comment: @AdrianHumphrey Unless something else happened you haven't lost any changes - that message is git telling you that it's refusing to do the pull until it knows how you want to handle your outstanding changes.

Comment: All I want to do at this point is get the code back that I stashed. How do I do this because I can not find it. I rent to my local repository and typed git stash. It said `Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 681bce3 Fix all the API calls. Replaced all buckets calls with a catch. Added gradient navigation bar.
HEAD is now at 681bce3 Fix all the API calls. Replaced all buckets calls with a catch. Added gradient navigation bar.` How do I get this back ?? @Conduit ?

Comment: To apply the stashed changes after pulling, call `git stash apply`. Afterward you will have to handle any merge conflicts that arise. After ensuring everything has gone smoothly you can drop the most recently stashed changes with `git stash drop`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118117/discussion-between-conduit-and-adrian-humphrey).